# CMake Error: Problem with archive_write_finish_entry(): Can't restore time

Tags: cmake, visualgdb

I am getting this problem when trying to cross compile OpenCV with VisualGDB
following this tutorial https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/opencv/build/

I also get the same error when typing `tar -xf b624b995ec9c439cbc2e9e6ee940d3a2-v0.1.1f.zip` from command line.

Where in CMakeList is it using the command `tar.exe`? Is it possible to replace it with something that does not error out like 7zip? Or can this be fixed by updating tar?

I have not been able to remove or replace `tar.exe` from C:\windows\System32 even as administrator

Is there a workaround to this problem?

Looking around online, tar does not even support zip files, why is it trying to unzip a zip file?

Thanks

```
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ENUM_COMPARE_SWITCH
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ENUM_COMPARE_SWITCH - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SUGGEST_OVERRIDE
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SUGGEST_OVERRIDE - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_INCONSISTENT_MISSING_OVERRIDE
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_INCONSISTENT_MISSING_OVERRIDE - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_CLASS_MEMACCESS
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_CLASS_MEMACCESS - Success
ADE: Download: v0.1.1f.zip
CMake Error: Problem with archive_write_finish_entry(): Can't restore time
CMake Error: Problem extracting tar: E:/Projects/temp/OpenCV/opencv/.cache/ade/b624b995ec9c439cbc2e9e6ee940d3a2-v0.1.1f.zip
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVDownload.cmake:240 (message):
  ADE: Unpack failed: 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  modules/gapi/cmake/DownloadADE.cmake:5 (ocv_download)
  modules/gapi/cmake/init.cmake:19 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:312 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:375 (_add_modules_1)
  modules/CMakeLists.txt:7 (ocv_glob_modules)

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "E:/Projects/temp/OpenCV/opencv/VisualGDB/Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "E:/Projects/temp/OpenCV/opencv/VisualGDB/Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
CMake Deprecation Warning:
  The 'cmake-server(7)' is deprecated.  Please port clients to use the
  'cmake-file-api(7)' instead.

Exception reported by CMake server: Configuration failed.
wh1+x: Exception reported by CMake server: Configuration failed.
   at wh1.c2[_InType,_OutType](_InType a)
   at g61.x(String[] a)
   at g61.l_2(Hello a)
   at wh1.m1()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
...
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_CLASS_MEMACCESS - Success
ADE: Download: v0.1.1f.zip
CMake Error: Problem with archive_write_finish_entry(): Can't restore time
CMake Error: Problem extracting tar: E:/Projects/opencv/.cache/ade/b624b995ec9c439cbc2e9e6ee940d3a2-v0.1.1f.zip
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVDownload.cmake:240 (message):
```

I traced the problem to `cmake\opencvdownload.cmake` where on line 236

`execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E tar xzf "${CACHE_CANDIDATE}"
                    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${DL_DESTINATION_DIR}"
                    RESULT_VARIABLE res)`

Where if I run the same command line I get this error:

```
opencv\.cache\ade>cmake -E tar xzf b624b995ec9c439cbc2e9e6ee940d3a2-v0.1.1f.zip
CMake Error: Problem with archive_write_finish_entry(): Can't restore time
CMake Error: Problem extracting tar: b624b995ec9c439cbc2e9e6ee940d3a2-v0.1.1f.zip
```

Whereas if I replace it with 7zip, it works fine
`7z x b624b995ec9c439cbc2e9e6ee940d3a2-v0.1.1f.zip`

However, CMake won't allow me to execute a 7zip command from command line
using "Cmake -E ..."

So the temporary solution until they either fix this in OpenCV or Cmake

Modify file `cmake\opencvdownload.cmake` on Line 236 
change

`execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E tar xzf "${CACHE_CANDIDATE}"`

to

`execute_process(COMMAND 7z x "${CACHE_CANDIDATE}"`